# How to find whether a Python program runs after is has been called by an Excel VBA program

Tags: python, excel, vba, parameters, call

I'm able to run a Python program from Excel VBA.
As this Pyhton program can be run either from Excel VBA or in stand-alone mode, I need something in the Pyhton program to find out which way it is running (as I have to apply small changes in the execution).

What kind of parameter (or similar stuff) can I query/identify within the Python program to find out whether it has been called by Excel VBA or not?

I would rather prefer not to pass parameters from Excel VBA to Python (it does not seem obvious).

Comment: How are you running your Python program? Are you invoking it via the [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) function? If so, passing command-line switches should be straightforward.

Comment: I'm using the following line in VBA : objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript, 1, True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the behavior of your Python script needs to change based on how it's called, it would be much more reliable to build a command-line switch into your script. This would also make it explicit when the behavior should change. Given that your are also writing the VBA macro that calls your Python script, you can control when the switch is used.

I know you mentioned you would prefer to avoid passing parameters to your Python script, but your parenthetical remark suggests your reason for avoiding parameters is that it's not clear how to do it with [`WScript.Shell.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84)).

Here's how you can pass a command-line switch to a Python script from VBA using `WScript.Shell.Run`.

```vb
Sub RunCommand()
    Dim shellObj As Object, result As Integer, strCommand As String
    Dim pythonPath As String, pythonScript As String
    
    Set shellObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    pythonPath = "C:\Path\to\python.exe"
    pythonScript = "C:\Path\to\do_something.py"
    strCommand = pythonPath & " " & pythonScript & " --excel"
    result = shellObj.Run(strCommand, 1, True)
End Sub
```

`do_something.py`:

```py
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="do_something",
        description="Do some function"
    )
    parser.add_argument("-x", "--excel", action="store_true")
    args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    return args, unknown_args

def main():
    args, unknown = parse_args()
    if args.excel:
        do_some_excel_thingy()
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for sharing the code with the parameters, I'll use it (far better than my home-made solution). Hope a lot of people find my question and your answer as I never found anything really clear while searching!

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I wrote a solution that meets my expectation.
However, it can be improved if somebody knows how to diffenrentiate the "closed" and the "locked in read-only mode" statuses.

Meanwhile, here is my ouptut:

```
import os
def file_test(f):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.split(f)[0]):
        # folder exists, useless to tell the user
        if os.access(f, os.F_OK):
            # file exists, useless to tell the user
            try:
                os.rename(f, f)
                return "file is closed or locked"  # file is either closed or opened in read-only mode
            except:
                return "file is opened"  # file is opened in write mode
        else:
            return "file is unknown"  # file does not exist                        
    else:
        return "folder is unknown"  # folder does not exist
 
f = 'C:/Users/didie/OneDrive/Bureau/file_test.xlsb'  
print(file_test(f))
```

Hope it helps...